# Embed libraries to jar file

Tags: java, netbeans

I want to embed libraries to build a single jar file.

also i must notice that im using Netbeans IDE.

any ideas?(please explain or link to a good reference if you can)

**Better Solution using ANT:**

http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/java_warehouse/single_jar/

Answer (score 1):

They both do not answer your question , you need to use Ant .
Refer this forums thread for details http://www.coderanch.com/t/419419/vc/there-way-netbeans-include-external

Answer (score 1):

I used [One-jar](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/) to make easily distributable jar. Not sure if that fits here.